# SMSlog backup in android

Tags: android

please help me to find the code to store sms logs in android.I have to work on the app to store calllog and smslog.I got code for calllog but smslog I couldnt get the proper code.
I only need to get the name, number ,msgtext,date and time of smslog from the phone.please help me to get some code.Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution...

call this method...catch exception as u want and this will print all the sms details on LogCat...it also returns number of sms found...

```
public int getAllData() throws Exception {
    // Declarations
    int dataCount = 0;
    // Details to get
    String type = null;
    String number = null;
    String body = null;
    String _date = null;
    String date = null;
    // Query details
    Uri dbUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
    String[] projection = { "type",
                            "address",
                            "body",
                            "date" };
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = null;
    // Getting results of query
    Cursor smsInfoCursor = getContentResolver().query(dbUri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    // Displaying data
    Log.i(TAG, "Displaying SMS info");
    if (smsInfoCursor.getCount()>0) {
        smsInfoCursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            // type
            type = smsInfoCursor.getString(0);
            if (type == null)
                   type = "";
            Log.v("type", type);
            // number
            number = smsInfoCursor.getString(1);
            if (number == null)
                   number = "";
            Log.v("number", number);
            // body
            body = smsInfoCursor.getString(2);
            if (body == null)
                   body = "";
            Log.v("body", body);
           // date time of message
           date = smsInfoCursor.getString(3);
           if (date == null)
               date = "";
           Log.v("Date", date);
           Log.v("-----", "-----");
        } while(smsInfoCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    dataCount = smsInfoCursor.getCount();
    }
    smsInfoCursor.close();
    return dataCount;
}
```

You also have to add following permission in manifest...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

You can also modify selection args as you need...

Hope this works...:)